backup nokia isam 7360
Does anyone have an idea how to get a config overview from my nokia isam in a format like .cfg or .txt?
here what I have tried:
I use Oxidized for backing up my network devices.
However, I have two Nokia ISAM 7360 devices in my network with XGS-PON line cards.
One of them no longer allows backups because the CPU load is too high when executing the "info configure" command.
I tried splitting the command, but the problem persists. I also added sleep times after each command, but that didn't help either.
Nokia provides a backup command in the manual. Using this command, I can upload a full backup via TFTP. This works fine, but it results in many database files, whereas I need the configuration in a .txt format to track my differences with Git or diff commands.

OK? What was your question?

oh sorry i editet my entry with:
Does anyone have an idea how to get a config overview from my nokia isam in a format like .cfg or .txt?
